# Read string list with a lot of elements C#

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, foreach

I want to read (all datas from that list) but I dont know how can I do it in C#

```
        //Create a list to store the result
        List<string>[] list = new List<string>[2];
        list[0] = new List<string>();
        list[1] = new List<string>();

        //Open connection
        if (mysql.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mysql.connection);
            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Read the data and store them in the list
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                list[0].Add(dataReader["filename"] + "");
                list[1].Add(dataReader["hash"] + "");
            }

            //close Data Reader
            dataReader.Close();

            //close Connection
            mysql.CloseConnection();

            //return list to be displayed
            return list;
        }
```

If someone can tell it is possible to create array from that mysql selection with for example 2 index { "filename", "hash" }. In PHP I simply can do $array["filename"] = FILENAME; etc.

I want to read that datas as `dataReader["filename"]` in foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating multiple lists and trying to synchronize the arrays by their indexes, you can create a single collection, e.g. `List<Tuple<string, string>>`, or a  `List<SomeEntity>` to model all fields of the row, where `SomeEntity` is a simple POCO class modelling a row of data from the query.

e.g. Create a new POCO class to model the row:

```
public class FileNameHash 
{
   public string FileName {get; set;}
   public string Hash {get; set;}
   // Other fields in your query here
}
```

... And modify your fetching code

```
//Create a list to store the result
var list = new List<FileNameHash>();

using (var mysql = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mysql.connection))
using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   if (mysql.OpenConnection() == true)
   {
      //Read the data and store them in the list
      while (dataReader.Read())
      {
          list.Add(new FileNameHash
          {
            FileName = (string)dataReader["filename"],
            Hash = (string)dataReader["hash"]
            // .. Other fields here
          });
      }
      return list;
    }
}
```

Other:

- By wrapping `IDisposable` like `Connection`, `Command` and `DataReader` in a using, you avoid the issue of forgetting to close / dispose resources in all paths, including exceptions.
- Adding an empty string to object to cast to string isn't a good idea IMO - do the cast explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get your question, but I think you are pretty close: You can foreach over your filenames by using:

```
foreach(string filename in list[0])
```

and you can iterate over your hashes by using:

```
foreach(string hash in list[1])
```

You can simplify your code by not putting those two Lists in an array, i.e. just use:

```
List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
List<string> hashes = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

First create model class :

```
Public class FileAndHashCode
{
    public string name {get;set}
    public string hashCode{get;set}
}
```

Then create a method :

```
Public List<FileAndHashCode> getFileAndhashcode()
   {
       \\...
       List<FileAndHashCode> temp=new List<FileAndHashCode>();
       while (dataReader.Read()) 
       { 
           temp.add(new 
            FileAndHashCode{name=dataReader["fileName"].ToString()+" " , hashCode=dataReader["hash"].ToString()+" "});
       }
       return temp;
    }
```